# Getting user inputs from the STDIN in Octave using input()?

Tags: octave, stdin

Can any please help me why am I getting this error on running the Octave(version 3.8.1) code below-

```
a = input("");
b = input("");
printf("%d", a+b);
```

**./CandidateCode.m: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./CandidateCode.m: line 1:`a = input("");'**

Please help me in resolving this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run your Script CandidateCode.m from shell, you have to add an interpreter with shebang:

Your CandidateCode.m:

```
#!/usr/bin/octave -q
a = input("");
b = input("");
printf("%d", a+b);
```

If you want to run it from within Octave, just execute "CandidateCode" (without ./ and .m)

Comment: Yes, i executed using **octave CandidateCode.m** and working fine for me. thanks andy